# Check Device Type For GPUImage

Tags: objective-c, gpuimage, gpuimagestillcamera

GPUImage requires, for iPhone 4 and below, images smaller than 2048 pixels. The 4S and above can handle much larger. How can I check to see which device my app is currently running on? I haven't found anything in `UIDevice` that does what I'm looking for. Any suggestions/workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you don't need to check device type, you simply need to read the maximum texture size supported by the device. Luckily, there is a built-in method within GPUImage that does this for you:

```
GLint maxTextureSize = [GPUImageContext maximumTextureSizeForThisDevice];
```

The above will give you the maximum texture size for the device you're running this on. That will determine the largest image size that GPUImage can work with on that device, and should be future-proof against whatever iOS devices come next.

This method works by caching the results of this OpenGL ES query:

```
 glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &maxTextureSize);
```

if you're curious.

I should also note that you can provide images larger than the max texture size to the framework, but they get scaled down to the largest size supported by the GPU before processing. At some point, I may complete my plan for tiling subsections of these images in processing so that larger images can be supported natively. That's a ways off, though.

Comment: So you're saying I don't need to manually resize it, the framework will resize it automatically if it's too large?

Comment: @Rob - For still images and photos taken by the camera, yes. I don't believe the raw data input does so right now.

Comment: I'm using UIImagePickerController right now. Would that be a problem?

Comment: @Rob - I assume you're then feeding the UIImage it gets into the framework as a GPUImagePicture instance. If so, that should be fine because that class will resize the image as necessary.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Brad! Does GPUImage have a resize function? I can't seem to find them, if there are any.

Comment: @Rob - At any point in the pipeline, an image size can be enlarged or reduced by using -forceProcessingAtSize: or -forceProcessingAtSizeRespectingAspectRatio:. This will only give you linear interpolation, though, which doesn't always produce the best results. For a cleaner resizing, I highly recommend using the GPUImageLanczosResamplingFilter when you force the size to something larger or smaller. It does a much better job.

Comment: This is kind of off topic, but I couldn't find an answer elsewhere and it seems far too simple to ask a question about... but does GPUImage have a function to utilize the GPU for something like the CALayer renderInContext function? The Core Animation one is ridiculously slow for full size camera images, and I need to render all the subviews.

Comment: @Rob - Why are you needing to render out photo-containing CALayers? Why not work from the original picture?

Comment: It has UILabel subviews that need to be rendered with it. I don't know of a better way to do it, and my googling has turned up nothing.

Answer (score 2):

This is among the best device-detection libraries I've come across: https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension

EDIT: Although the readme seems to suggest that the more up-to-date versions are in her "Cookbook" sources. Perhaps [this one](https://github.com/erica/iOS-6-Advanced-Cookbook/blob/master/C01%20-%20Device/02%20-%20UIDevice-Hardware) is more current.

Comment: Specifically you want the `UIDevice-Hardware.h` file and the `platformType` method.

Comment: You'll need the .m file too, but yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a useful class that I have used several times in the past that is very simple and easy to implement,

https://gist.github.com/Jaybles/1323251